# Issue while converting date to datetime format in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Here is the dataframe. I want the dates here in `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` format.

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['2017-18','','','','','','','','','','','',''], ['COMPANIES', '01-APR-2017', '01-MAY-2017', '01-JUN-2017', 
                    '01-JULY-2017', '01-AUG-2017', '01-SEP-2017', '01-OCT-2017', '01-NOV-2017', '01-DEC-2017', '01-JAN-2018', '01-FEB-2018', '01-MAR-2018']])
```

I tried,

```
df2.iloc[1, 1:] = df2.iloc[1, 1:].str.replace("JULY", "JUL")
df2.iloc[1, 1:] = df2.iloc[1, 1:].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%d-%b-%Y')
```

but, it gives:

```
          0                    1                    2                    3   \
0    2017-18                                                                  
1  COMPANIES  1491004800000000000  1493596800000000000  1496275200000000000   

                    4                    5                    6   \
0                                                                  
1  1498867200000000000  1501545600000000000  1504224000000000000   

                    7                    8                    9   \
0                                                                  
1  1506816000000000000  1509494400000000000  1512086400000000000   

                    10                   11                   12  
0                                                                 
1  1514764800000000000  1517443200000000000  1519862400000000000
```

Am I missing something? Is there any other way to achieve the dates in required format?

I even tried:

```
for i in df2.iloc[1, 1:]:
    i = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but gives a `ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `strftime` using `.dt`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['2017-18','','','','','','','','','','','',''], ['COMPANIES', '01-APR-2017', '01-MAY-2017', '01-JUN-2017', 
                    '01-JULY-2017', '01-AUG-2017', '01-SEP-2017', '01-OCT-2017', '01-NOV-2017', '01-DEC-2017', '01-JAN-2018', '01-FEB-2018', '01-MAR-2018']])


df2.iloc[1, 1:] = df2.iloc[1, 1:].str.replace("JULY", "JUL")
df2.iloc[1, 1:] = df2.iloc[1, 1:].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%d-%b-%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(df2)
```

**Output:**

```
          0                    1                    2                    3   \
0    2017-18                                                                  
1  COMPANIES  2017-04-01 00:00:00  2017-05-01 00:00:00  2017-06-01 00:00:00   

                    4                    5                    6   \
0                                                                  
1  2017-07-01 00:00:00  2017-08-01 00:00:00  2017-09-01 00:00:00   

                    7                    8                    9   \
0                                                                  
1  2017-10-01 00:00:00  2017-11-01 00:00:00  2017-12-01 00:00:00   

                    10                   11                   12  
0                                                                 
1  2018-01-01 00:00:00  2018-02-01 00:00:00  2018-03-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you should transpose your dataframe and use `dateutil.parser`, which is more flexible with regards to date input format.

Structurally, `pandas` works best and most intuitively when you have series (or columns) of fixed types.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['2017-18','','','','','','','','','','','',''], ['COMPANIES', '01-APR-2017', '01-MAY-2017', '01-JUN-2017', 
                    '01-JULY-2017', '01-AUG-2017', '01-SEP-2017', '01-OCT-2017', '01-NOV-2017', '01-DEC-2017', '01-JAN-2018', '01-FEB-2018', '01-MAR-2018']])
```

**Solution**

```
res = df2.T.iloc[1:, 1].apply(parser.parse)
```

**Result**

```
print(res)

1    2017-04-01
2    2017-05-01
3    2017-06-01
4    2017-07-01
5    2017-08-01
6    2017-09-01
7    2017-10-01
8    2017-11-01
9    2017-12-01
10   2018-01-01
11   2018-02-01
12   2018-03-01
Name: 1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I would avoid using `apply()` and `parser`. Instead just calling the parser function (I recommend using `pd.to_datetime()`) on the data, like shown in my example, is more intuitive and faster (and easier to debug).

Comment: @Scotty1-, that's what I'd normally say, but I find the other answers (convert JULY to JUL to fit `datetime` conversion format) a poor alternative. Test it with OP's data - it won't work without this replacement.

Comment: That is true. I already forgot about that conversion But I'd still try to avoid using `.apply()`... I'll upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp is saved in two different rows. The first row contains one timestamp and several empty entries. The second row contains the string `'COMPANIES'` AND datetimes as strings. Now when you try to parse these datetime strings to datetime format, they will be parsed and then converted to the absolute numeric date format, like `1506816000000000000`.

This is because `pandas` stores the second row as `dtype=object`, since it is of mixed types: strings and datetimes.
To represent the datetimes correctly, they need to be stored in a row/columns with a correct `dtype`.
To show you the effect of storing them separately:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df2.iloc[1, 1:], format = '%d-%b-%Y')
```

Btw.: Why is everyone using `apply()`? Just calling a function on a row/column directly is alot faster and more intuitive.